# Let radio buttons keep value after refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, save

I am making an absence control where you can select the absence per user with radio buttons. Per user you can select either Present ("Aanwezig"), Absent("Afwezig") or Allowed Absent ("Geoorloofd afwezig").This means that there are many radio buttons on one page. I want to make sure that the input doesn't get lost if you haven't pressed "save" yet and refresh the page. How can I do this?

I saw that Javascript has onkeypress=myFunction(), so I thought, that might be useful to put in the radio buttons, but I don't know what myFunction() should be for it to work... I have basically no experience with javascript and I couldn't really find the solution online, since I saw no examples with Django.

**So my question is: How can I make sure that the input gets saved in some way so it stays that way after refreshing the page?**

```
 <form action="{% url 'create_attendance' baksgewijs.id peloton.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="table-responsive fixed-length">
                <table id = "userTable">
                        <tbody>
                        {% for user in users %}
                                <tr>
                                        <td> {{ user }}
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name={{user.id}} id="radio" value="Aanwezig">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                                    Aanwezig
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name={{user.id}} id="radio" value="Afwezig">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                                                    Afwezig
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name={{user.id}} id="radio" value="Geoorloofd afwezig">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault3">
                                                   Geoorloofd afwezig
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sla baksgewijs op" class="btn btn-primary active">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_web_storage.asp), or Session storage. The state of the html will be put back to original on refresh, to save it you'll have to save its state and make the first thing the webpage does is to retrieve that state. PS. this is the vanilla way to do this

```html
<html>

<script>
let absent = sessionStorage.getItem('absent');
if(absent){ //absent will be null if there is no saved key in storage
let checkbox = document.getElementByName('absent');
checkbox.value = absent;

}
</script>



<form id="mainForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="absent" onchange="(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  sessionStorage.setItem('absent', e.target.value);
}"/>
```

Comment: local storage is until it is removed  while session storage is until the user leaves the tab

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can apply this example to my code, since my name isn't just a string, but {{user.id}} since it is unique for each user?

Comment: Hey there, I was just using input.name as a way to identify the form element the data came from. you can use the id or any other way to access it youd like, as for saving to sessionstorage. you can save any value to it as long as it is Serializable using the JSON.stringify function. I dont know what type {{user.id}} but assuming its either a string or a number, you can use it as the key to differentiate the different inputs. or you can put all the values into a dictionary ( called objects in JS) and save them with a single key

Comment: `let save = {input1: "absent", input2:"excused"}; let saveAsString = JSON.stringify(save)// converts to string; sessionStroage.setItem('yourkey', saveAsString)`

Comment: User.id gives the id of the user per user, so the list of all id's would look like [1, 18, 4] etc. I am not really sure if I understand how I can make a dictionairy of that, since the length of this list depends on the amount of users...?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in multiple ways,

1- You can use `Local Storage` If you want to store this value without expiration time.

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

2- You can use `Session Storage` the value will be stored even if you refresh the page, but whenever the browser tab is closed, it will be deleted.

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

3- You can use `Cookies`, with `cookies` you can specify the expiration date yourself.

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie